# Prove or disprove: If $f_*: \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1 (Y,y)$ is an isomorphism and $X=Y, x=y$, then $f_*$ is the identity map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $f_*: \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1 (Y,y)$ is an isomorphism and $X=Y, x=y$, then $f_*$ is the identity map.

The map is from $[a] \mapsto [f \circ a]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.

Consider, for instance, $f \colon S^1 \to S^1$, $e^{it} \mapsto e^{-it}$. Here $f$ is already an homeomorphism (of pointed spaces, as $f(1) = 1$), so induces an isomorphism $f_* \colon {\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ of fundamental groups. But $f_*$ is not the identity; it is multiplication by $-1$.